# How to escape back ticks

Tags: go

MySQL requires tables that shadow reserved words to be back ticked. I have a table Role which is a reserved word, but I have already put my query in back ticks so I can write it over multiple lines (this is a toy query, large ones will not fit on one line).

How do I escape the back ticks?

Here is my code:

```
dbmap := db.InitDb()

var roles []entities.Role
query :=
    ` << Difficult to see with SO's code editor widget, but here is a back tick
SELECT *
FROM `Role` <<< Needs escaping
`  << Difficult to see, but here is a back tick

_, err := dbmap.Select(&roles, query, nil)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(roles)
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You cannot escape backticks inside backticks, but you can do:

```
dbmap := db.InitDb()

var roles []entities.Role
query := `
SELECT *
FROM ` + "`Role`"

_, err := dbmap.Select(&roles, query, nil)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(roles)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `.` prefix:

```
query := `
SELECT *
FROM .Role
`
```

Answer (score 5):

If your query is long, it might be worth putting in a text file and reading it in, that will keep your code more concise and organized, and also avoid the backtick quoting issue entirely.

Comment: I was thinking of doing exactly that when the going gets heavy, I can then use a tool like Navicat and get syntax highlighting and autocomplete etc.

Comment: Excellent idea, you can also name the file in a self-explanatory way.

Comment: But be careful when you read the file as byte-array, it might then contain the byte-order mark.

Comment: I'd also consider that this makes your binary less portable as you have to remember to bring the sql file along as well.

Comment: This is an entirely different problem, but I embed the SQL files in the file using github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata, so distribution is easier

Comment: You can now use the [//go:embed directive](https://pkg.go.dev/embed)

Comment: @donatJ you could `embed` it

Comment: Do you know the current directory? Doubt it. Do you know the full runtime path at compile time? Doubt it. If you think you know the current directory, you might be wrong. Some foolish code (that might not even exist yet) might set it in another thread. Paths are hell.

Answer (score 5):

I just used a placeholder (like the unicode `”` or basically anything which won't appear anywhere else in the query) instead of the backticks and replaced them afterwards:

```
strings.ReplaceAll(`CREATE TABLE ”mydatabase”.”mytable” (
    ”id” binary(16),
    ”sname” varchar(45),
    PRIMARY KEY(”id”)
)`, "”", "`")
```

(Thanks to Andrey Tarantsov for proposing `”` as a placeholder.)

Comment: A good choice, but oh my gosh, why %s?! :) You can even use some Unicode quotes like ”.

Comment: @AndreyTarantsov Good point. I guess, I was kinda used to `%s` as placeholder. But thinking about it, it's a bit hard to read and might bring some confusion with `fmt` verbs. I'll adjust the response according to your advice! :)

Comment: This works but terrible code style imo... 

Comment: @Dion That's true, and I wouldn't recommend to use it extensively. But in situations where you have a lenghty query and don't want to read it from a file (for whatever reasons), imo this solution maintains the most readibility compared to the other suggestions here. I didn't intend to advocate this style - if you can keep `.sql` files separately or you don't depend on readability, there's no reason to do it that way.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no decent solution for that in Go. I just went to only using the sql backticks when really necessary (that basically only is the case when a column name matches an sql keyword). With that it's possible to use the go backticks for multiline queries and in case a backtick is necessary you can use the regular string concat like
```
`CREATE TABLE mydatabase.mytable(` +
"`count` int (11)," + 
` ... rest of the query`
```

Comment: "Unfortunately there is no decent solution for that in Go" is a proper roundup for many Go patterns anyway imo. ;( I think you're approach is fine, too, but I'ld personally rather not rely on the fact that in 99.9% of all cases schema and table names don't need to be escaped, just for the one 0.01 % biting back when you expect it the least.

Answer (score 4):

Use notepad++ on your plain text and replace (search and) replace

```
`
```

with

```
`+"`"+`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try writing queries like this:

```
query :=fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM `Role`")
```

You can compare the outputs:

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
 query :=fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM `Role`")
 fmt.Println(query)
 fmt.Println( `SELECT * FROM ` + "`Role`") }
```

Comment: That's not multiline

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Go Templates you can pass the backtick in as a parameter:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "text/template"
    "bytes"
)

func main() {
    template,_ := template.New( "greeting").Parse(`Hello {{ .BT }}{{ .FirstName }}{{ .BT }}`)
    data := struct {
        FirstName string
        BT        string
    }{
        FirstName:"bob",
        BT:"`", // <---- Here!
    }
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    _ = template.Execute(&buf, data)
    fmt.Print(buf.String())
}
```

gives:

```
 Hello `bob`
```