# Sql syntax error Golang

Tags: mysql, go

I've just started learning Golang.

I followed the example_test in Golang source [ExampleDB_Query_multipleResultSets](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/database/sql/example_test.go#L48)

then I modified my query likely:

```
`
create table uid (id bigint);

select id from user where age < ?;

SELECT user.id, user.name FROM user JOIN uid ON user.id = uid.id;

select ur.user, ur.role from user_roles as ur join uid on uid.id = ur.user;
`
```

table user:

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| name  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| age   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and uid:

```
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I recieved the error from log:

```
2017/02/21 14:44:08 Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select id from user where age < ?;

SELECT user.id, user.name FROM user JOIN uid' at line 3
exit status 1
```

Comment: `user` is a reserved word, escape it with backticks.

Comment: I used backticks to wrap my query, so I can not use it to wrap *user*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198980/golang-how-to-escape-back-ticks (ugly unfortunately)

Comment: yup, you right, thanks