# How to escape a backtick inside a Go struct tag

Tags: go

I want to escape a backtick inside a Go struct tag. For example in the code below:

```
type User struct {
   email string `validate: "regexp=`"`
   password string `validate: "min=8"`

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape back ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198980/how-to-escape-back-ticks)

Comment: I cannot concat strings in struct tags. I get this error `build command-line-arguments: cannot load gopkg.in/validator.v2: module gopkg.in/validator.v2: Get https://proxy.golang.org/gopkg.in/validator.v2/@v/list: unexpected EOF
`

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question: escaping backticks in struct tags cannot be done with any of the answers listed in that question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use regular quotes. You'll just have to escape more characters, especially the quotes around the value part of the struct tag.

```
type User struct {
   Email string "validate:\"regexp=`\""
   Password string `validate:"min=8"`
}
```

And verify the tag value with reflection:

```
func main() {
  s := reflect.ValueOf(&User{}).Elem()
  fmt.Println(s.Type().Field(0))
}
```

Outputs:

```
{Email  string validate:"regexp=`" 0 [0] false}
```

Comment: It does compile, and seems like it's working. Thanks :)