# How to escape nested back quotes

Tags: go

Code example：

```golang
func main() {
    regx:= `
[^`]
 `
}
```

```golang
./main.go:9:4: syntax error: unexpected ] at end of statement
./main.go:10:1: string not terminated
```

How to solve back quotes nested back quotes？

Comment: You don't https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24475 maybe `regx := "\n[^\`]\n"` will do the trick though https://go.dev/play/p/_ZGCAv8HdwY

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198980/how-to-escape-back-ticks

Answer (score 0):

I see what you want but we cannot escape backticks inside backticks. However, you can do something like the following.

```
    regx := `
[^` + "`" + `]
`
```